# How to scrape dt and dd at once with scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

How to crawl website : https://kateglo.com/?mod=dictionary&srch=all
for `dt` and `dd` tag values simultaneously.

I Have tried and succeed but dt and dd not same line

Sorry about bad english.

Comment: Hi, it's not important, you can scrap all tag type. (response.css('dd::text').get())

Comment: response.css('dt::text').get()

Comment: <dd><span class="label label-info">bt</span> <b>1</b> alat; <b>2</b> yang memiliki, mengandung, atau bersifat; <b>3</b> berulang (terus-menerus); <b>4</b> mengandung (bersifat); </dd>
i dont get nothing, i want to get all text value, Please help :(, this is for my school assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two ways.

First one is less reliable - just extract two lists and zip them:

```
dt_list = response.css('dt::text').extract()
dd_list = response.css('dd::text').extract()

final_list = zip(dt_list, dd_list)
```

You'll get list of tuples with corresponding `dt` and `dd` values.

---

Second one is more correct but will require reading docs a bit. You should take a look at [xPath Following sibling](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp)

Finally you'll get something like this:

```
dt_list = response.css('dt')
for dt in dt_list:
    dt_value = dt.css('::text').get()
    # Getting corresponding dd value
    dd_value = dt.xpath('./following-sibling::dd/text()').get()
```

So it goes.

Comment: Thanks before, but is dd_value: none

Comment: i have tried "response.css('dd::text').getall()" but i get all value, i want to get 1 dt and 1 dd value, and loop until end page

Comment: Updated code. There was a bug in last string. Now it works.

Comment: i have tried your code before, but if <dd> tag have <b> tag, it still have none value, thanks you so much before for your guidance

link i have tried is : https://kateglo.com/index.php?op=1&phrase=&lex=n&type=&src=&mod=dictionary&srch=Cari

Comment: I stuck, please help 

Comment: you can try to vary xpath: `./following-sibling::dd/b/text()` or `./following-sibling::dd//text()`